# Codemirror tabs to spaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, codemirror

I'm using Codemirror in an app. Has anyone found a way to make it uses spaces when using tab? When I press enter to go to a new line it uses spaces. However, if I backspace to the beginning of the line, and use a tab instead, it inserts it as a tab instead of 2 or 4 spaces or whatever I have it set to. Then, when I view the rendered view, my code has like 8 spaces for indentations in the areas where I used the tab key. Is there some option or way to convert actual tabs to spaces in Codemirror?

I'm also using the codemirror-rails gem, which may not be as up-to-date as the actual Codemirror version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would override the default tab key functionality and replace it with this function.
Add this to your Codemirror configurations.

```
extraKeys: {
            "Tab": function(cm){
              cm.replaceSelection("   " , "end");
            }
           }
```

[Demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aljordan82/hC7jP/)

Comment: Pass `"end"` as a second arg to `replaceSelection` and you can omit the second call.